# how to call function in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, select, sql-function

how to call oracle function . i want to call below function but its show error i am new in oracle that's why i'm here

```
  Function CardExpiry(cardNO char) return date;
```

i am using below query but it's show error

```
SELECT * from SMIT.AUDIO_Service_Package.CardExpiry(:CARDNO) ;
```

error
 [Error: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your function returns a scalar value, you cannot select *from* it.

Presumably, you want:

```
SELECT SMIT.AUDIO_Service_Package.CardExpiry(:CARDNO) FROM DUAL;
```

Comment: what is DUAL ??

Comment: DUAL is table name ??

Comment: `DUAL` is a pseudo table, like dummy. If you `SELECT 1 FROM DUAL`, you get `1`.

Comment: @AddiKhan Oracle SQL (and ANSI, I believe, if we're doing that) requires a FROM clause, and anything in a FROM clause has to be a table or view or equivalent. So you can't just `select upper('hello')`, and you certainly can't `select * from upper('hello')`.